# iOS Voiceover - detect if vertical navigation is enabled on rotor?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, voiceover, uiaccessibility

In iOS, is there a way to detect if a user has 'Vertical Navigation' enabled on their UIAccessibility Voiceover Rotor?

Thank you.

Comment: Please read our [ask] page to refresh yourself on how to post a question here on SO. As it is right now, the question does not meet the guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enabled states of many accessibility features can be queried programmatically ([see the "Capabilities" section of the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility)), but user preferences are generally not available to developers.